# OpenTelemetry sidecar wait for client data flush

Tags: docker, docker-compose, open-telemetry

I use open telemetry for tracing and metrics. I have a pretty standard setup - there is a service that produces metrics/traces and an open telemetry sidecar that collects these metrics and pushes them to AWS:

```
services:
  service:
    build:
      context: .
    image: service
    container_name: service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - aws-otel-collector
  aws-otel-collector:
    image: public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:latest
    container_name: aws-otel-collector
    ports:
      - "4317:4317"
```

Service flushes metrics and shuts down an exporter on service shutdown:

```golang
shutdown, err := initMetricProvider(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        log.Printf("Shutting down metric provider")
        if err := shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("failed to shutdown metric provider: %w", err))
        }
    }()

    meter := global.MeterProvider().Meter("service")
    counter, err := meter.SyncInt64().Counter("test")
```

From time to time I am getting errors during restarts, caused by an inability to push metrics on a shutdown, smth like:

```
max retry time elapsed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4317: connect: connection refused"
```

This happens because the otel collector sidecar is getting suspended before metrics are flushed in service.

Question: how does one guarantees the sidecar waits until metrics are flushed? is there a way to have a delay on sidecar shutdown? (it didn't manage to find this in otel documentation)

Comment: What are you using? ECS, EKS,...?

Comment: ECS in this case